# Watir-webdriver clean tmp files

Tags: webdriver, watir-webdriver

Is possible to create the tmp folders `webdriver-profile20120306-5313-a3chgu` im a specific folder?

Or delect when closing browser ?

Tanks

Comment: I see a clear_cookies but not other temp files. Maybe clear_cookies includes the other temp files. If not, maybe Ruby can do that directly.

Comment: But i dont know witch folder it creates so i cant delete then.

Comment: This is likely something down at the webdriver level.  Adding the webdriver tag.

Comment: What do you mean with "Adding the webdriver tag"

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for Firefox (as I did not see this folder created for Chrome or IE)?

If so, Watir-Webdriver automatically deletes the temporary folder when you run:

```
browser.close()
```

As seen in the following test, a profile directory exists after opening Firefox and none exist after closing Firefox.

```
temp_dir = 'C:/Documents and Settings/Setup/Local Settings/Temp/'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

temp_profiles = Dir.entries(temp_dir).select {|entry| entry =~ /webdriver-profile/} 
puts temp_profiles.length # => 1

browser.close

temp_profiles = Dir.entries(temp_dir).select {|entry| entry =~ /webdriver-profile/}  
puts temp_profiles.length # => 0
```

Does this work for you or do you want/need to close the browser manually?